# Twitter intent with % sign

Tags: html, twitter

My Tweet button has the following href value: "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Yields in Tanzania" . How do I include 20%? My output should be: "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Yields in Tanzania is 20%" - This is giving me 324 Error Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%` is used in urls to encode unsafe characters.  In order to physically pass a `%`, you have to encode it.  The percent sign has a hexidecimal value of 25 in ISO-8859-1 (the encoding used).

So, you actually should use:

```
"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Yields in Tanzania is 20%25"
```

Comment: And, for that mater, you should actually replace spaces with %20.    "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Yields%20in%20Tanzania%20is%2020%25"